# avoid data loss when stopping python script that runs in windows command prompt

Tags: python, windows, bash

I've written a Python-script, that scrapes certain websites. I run it from windows command line and use the command line to direct the "print()"-output of the script into a txt-file.

Like this:

MyScraper.py > outputOfMyScraper.txt.

Now and then I have to kill/stop the script before the run is complete (I close the windows command line). 9 of 10 times this has no impact on the outputOfMyScraper.txt-file, but now and then the content of the file will be deleted when closing the command line.

Is there - besides changing the code in the scraper to write content directly to a csv-file and avoid the windows command line totally - a way of stopping the script without the risk of losing data?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Check this http://superuser.com/questions/764479/force-output-buffer-flush-in-running-program

Comment: thanks. Most of that is plain jibberish to me :)

Comment: And rather, end the script with `Ctrl+Break` instead of closing the console window.

Comment: If the performance hit of using unbuffered I/O is too unbearable, then use ctypes to call [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016) to set a ctypes callback as a control handler. If the control event is anything but 0 (i.e. Ctrl+C), handle it by flushing the file. This includes Ctrl+Break and also the control close event when the console is closed. The console gives each attached process 5 seconds to handle the close event, which should be enough time to flush the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force Python to switch standard output to unbuffered mode by adding `-u` switch:

```
python -u MyScraper.py > outputOfMyScraper.txt
```

Another way is to set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable to non-empty string:

```
set PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
MyScraper.py > outputOfMyScraper.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, Antti. I'll try this.